# How to use a Nested type on a user control on XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nested

I have the follow code in Container.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfLibraries.Container"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Border x:Name="Group" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="20" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,5,5">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=Group}" BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, ElementName=Group}" Margin="0,-20,0,0" >
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Group" FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I Would like to place nested types in the Stack panel "ContentPanel" like this:

```
 <local:Container HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
     <local:Container.ContentPanel>
     <!--More controls will be placed here-->
     </local:Container.ContentPanel>
 </local:Container>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific like what is `local` ?

Comment: @AbinMathew He or she is trying to put the UserControl he is currently writing, into the that same UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what effect you are trying to accomplish here. But if I understand correctly, you simply want to be able to add children to the `UserControl`'s own `StackPanel` named `"ContentPanel"`, but from the client code that uses the `UserControl`.

If that's correct, then the simplest way to accomplish this is to simply expose that `StackPanel`'s `Children` property in the `UserControl`:

```
class Container : UserControl
{
    public UIElementCollection ContentPanelChildren
    {
        get { return this.ContentPanel.Children; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then when you want to add children to the panel in client XAML, you can just do something like this:

```
<local:Container HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <local:Container.ContentPanelChildren>
     <TextBlock Text="Sample child content"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Other sample child content"/>
  </local:Container.ContentPanelChildren>
</local:Container>
```

Note, of course, that the public property must have a different name than the private field generated by the `x:Name` for the `StackPanel` element. You won't be able to name them both `"ContentPanel"`.

If this does not address your actual question, please be more specific. Provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to accomplish, with a specific description of what that code does and what you'd like it to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, I don't think you can do this. You are creating an infinite loop there. Because every `Container` object you have there, it is going to have a child `Container` object within. That very same child `Container` object will **definitely** have a child `Container` in it too. Convert that to pure code and it is almost similar to writing this:

```
public void MyFunction()
{
    this.MyFunction();
}
```

You call `MyFunction()` once and your program is going to loop endlessly.